# Determination of delivery pressure from pump in my Parts Washer

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, hydraulics, fluid, liquid

We want to know how can we determine the pressure of the liquid at the delivery end of the pump. We have a centrifugal pump and a 2" pipeline at the delivery end. Pump delivery performance as per catalog is 510LPM @20 mtr head to 348LPM @36mtr head.

The delivery pipe is connected to a manifold on which spray nozzles are connected around 70 Nos.

The total length of pipe from the pump outlet to the spray manifold will be approx 5 metres of which 1.5mtr is vertical & remaining horizontal.

We have mounted a pressure gauge on the line which gives a constant reading of 0.6-0.8 Kg/cm2 which is lower is lower than our expectations from a 5HP pump.

When we block the line just before the manifold, the gauge shows a reading of 3.5-4 kg/cm2.

Kindly help us determine the process of finding out the pressure in the line.

Also, If I have to select a pump that constantly delivers liquid at 3 Kg/Cm2, how do I go about the selection?